# What is an adjective or term you use to describe someone obsessed with petty or trivial gains?

Tags: word-request

Say a person is willing to spend hours standing in line just for some useless freebie, or spend hours negotiating a one dollar discount on a 100-dollar product, or things like that, and be very happy about it.

What is the adjective or term for the person with such behavior, if there is one?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no *one* word. Not even in my native language where we have separate terms for almost everything under the sun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial question used two very good adjectives: petty and trivial, so good job! I would add niggling, piddling, penny-ante, and picayune. The last two have interesting sources and histories.

[He's always niggling over small details.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/niggle)

Of those, only four rather piddling victories went the liberals’ way.
—
[The Economist, "Justice Kennedy is retiring. What happens now?," 30 June 2018](https://www.economist.com/united-states/2018/06/30/justice-kennedy-is-retiring.-what-happens-now)

[penny-ante](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/penny-ante)

[...Dole had become mired in the " nit-picking and penny ante politics " of partisan budget battles and was pitting himself against Senate Democrats while Clinton stood above the battle.](http://Dole%20had%20become%20mired%20in%20the%20%22%20nit-picking%20and%20penny%20ante%20politics%20%22%20of%20partisan%20budget%20battles%20and%20was%20pitting%20himself%20against%20Senate%20Democrats%20while%20Clinton%20stood%20above%20the%20battle.)

[I didn't want to seem picayune by criticizing.](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/picayune?s=t)

Other words that come to my mind are neurotic, spendthrift, and cheesy. These have differences in personal judgment of the character of the person, namely a little bit crazy or "off" for neurotic; cheap and miserly with money for "spendthrift," and of poor quality taste and character for "cheesy."

[He seemed a neurotic, self-obsessed character.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/neurotic)

[The spendthrift managed to blow all of his inheritance in a single year.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spendthrift)

[Cheesy plastic knickknacks lined the fireplace mantel.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cheesy)